# Is there a native templating system for plain text files in Python?

Tags: python, string, templates

I am looking for either technique or templating system for Python for formatting output to simple text. What I require is that it will be able to iterate through multiple lists or dicts. It would be nice if I would be able to define template into separate file (like output.templ) instead of hardcoding it into source code.

As simple example what I want to achieve, we have variables `title`, `subtitle` and `list`

```
title = 'foo'
subtitle = 'bar'
list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

And running throught a template, output would look like this:

```
Foo
Bar

Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

How to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if it is simple, but [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) might be of help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are quite a number of template engines for python: [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/), [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) [etc](http://www.google.de/search?q=python+template+engine). You won't make a mistake with any of them.

Comment: did the OP say 'native'? And validated something that isn't!

Answer (score 280):

You can use the standard library [string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) an its Template class.

Having a file `foo.txt`:

```
$title
$subtitle
$list
```

And the processing of the file (`example.py`):

```
from string import Template

d = {
    'title': 'This is the title',
    'subtitle': 'And this is the subtitle',
    'list': '\n'.join(['first', 'second', 'third'])
}

with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
    src = Template(f.read())
    result = src.substitute(d)
    print(result)
```

Then run it:

```
$ python example.py
This is the title
And this is the subtitle
first
second
third
```

Comment: Where, please, does the dictionary go?  Is it a separate file (and where is it stored), or is it included within the Python script, or included within foo.txt?

Comment: @lawlist: Added a full example at the end. The only thing missing were declarations for the data to be replaced into the template.

Comment: Why does the initial code snipped of *foo.txt* have a trailing `$` for the placeholders. That kinda threw me off a bit because it generates errors.

Comment: Use `$$` to escape and output `$`.

Comment: @Batandwa I don't get an error. Single `$` works fine on Python 3.4

Comment: do you need to close the file?

Comment: @Batandwa I do get an error on Python 2.7.3 and using $$ fixes it. Thanks from four years later.

Answer (score 20):

If your prefer to use something shipped with the standard library, take a look at the [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). By default it is not able to format lists like in your output example, but you can handle this with a [custom Formatter](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) which overrides the [`convert_field`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Formatter.convert_field) method.

Supposed your custom formatter `cf` uses the conversion code `l` to format lists, this should produce your given example output:

```
cf.format("{title}\n{subtitle}\n\n{list!l}", title=title, subtitle=sibtitle, list=list)
```

Alternatively you could preformat your list using `"\n".join(list)` and then pass this to your normal template string.

Comment: Dead simple for CLI output templating :)

Comment: Here is an example how to do this: https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2016/the-worlds-simplest-python-template-engine . A simple template engine with loops and conditions in 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

if you want arbitrary prefixes/suffixes to identify your variables, you can simply use `re.sub` with a lambda expression:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re

def tpl(fn:Path, v:dict[str,str]) -> str:
    text = fn.with_suffix('.html').read_text()
    return re.sub("(<!-- (.+?) -->)", lambda m: v[m[2].lower()], text)

html = tpl(Path(__file__), {
    'title' : 't',
    'body' : 'b'
})
```