# Python script receiving error for results output

Tags: python

Results not doesn't output . I get an error please help .

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this ? I'm just starting out in programming. I can run the script but the results don't show. I get an error please help.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385686/python-technique-or-simple-templating-system-for-plain-text-output/57044980?noredirect=1#comment100618288_57044980)

```
filein = open( 'IOS.j2' )
src = string.Template( filein.read() )

hostname = input("Enter the hostname: ")
subnet = input("Enter the third octet: ")
secret_type = input("Enter the secret_type: ")


d={ 'hostname':hostname, 'secret_type':secret_type }
result = src.substitute(d)

#print result

fileout = open( hostname + '.cfg', 'w' )
fileout.write(result)
```

Thanks for any help .

LogCat

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "rtrtemplate.py", line 33, in  result = src.substitute(d) File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\string.py", line 132, in substitute return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template) File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\string.py", line 129, in convert self._invalid(mo) File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\string.py", line 105, in _invalid (lineno, colno))

Comment: Can you provide some code? So that we could understand it better.

Comment: Sure thanks for the quick response I've included a link but here  is the code in question .

Comment: Any help with this would be much appreciated .

Comment: Does the print statement work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply again I get prompted for the additional parameters but I get this error message at the end .

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "rtrtemplate.py", line 33, in <module>
    result = src.substitute(d)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\string.py", line 132, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\string.py", line 129, in convert
    self._invalid(mo)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\string.py", line 105, in _invalid
    (lineno, colno))

Comment: Add your template, if you can

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-class-in-python/) guide.This should work.

Make sure your template is correctly formatted, dictionary labels match the template placeholders. If it persists post a comment.:)

Comment: Sorry about my very limited knowledge and thanks for the response so when  you mean formatted correctly you are talking about this section for the results  right ?#Substitute and store in the variable "result"
d={ 'hostname':hostname, 'secret_type':secret_type }
result = src.substitute(d)

Comment: python rtrtemplate.py
Enter the hostname:
Enter the third octet:
Enter the secret_type:
Enter the enable_secret:
Enter the radius_secret:
Enter the name_server:
Enter the domain_name:
Enter the snooping:
Enter the the path:
Enter the priority:
Enter the archive:
Enter the username_secret:
Enter the management_ip:
Enter the gateway:
Enter the ftp_secert:
Enter the location:
Enter the snmp_server:
Enter the password_secert:
Enter the ntp_server:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rtrtemplate.py", line 33, in <module>
    result = src.substitute(d)

Comment: So I changed the cfg template file for the imput to match $ for each entry and that seemed to work but when I started adding addtional line items. I got error on line 19 for results again. d={ 'hostname':hostname, 'subnet':subnet, 'nameserver':nameserver, 'enable secret':enablesecret, }
result = src.substitute(d) . I'm probably missing something so simple thanks for any help .

Comment: Thanks for posting that guide I think it's working now seems I had a lot of formatting problems in my cfg file and not the py thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry I was offline for a few days. Happy that it worked. Consider accepting the answer. If you found it useful. Cheers.