# Insert variables into an html file

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email using sendgrid. For this I created an html file and I want to format some variables into it.

Very basic test.html example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        Hello World, {name}!
    </body>
</html>
```

Now in my Python code I am trying to do something like this:

```py
html = open("test.html", "r")
text = html.read()

msg = MIMEText(text, "html")
msg['name'] = 'Boris'

and then proceed to send the email
```

Sadly, this does not seem to be working. Any way to make this work?

Comment: Using [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/nativetypes/) will be helpful here

Comment: Use templating? Maybe jinja. Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/6385940/1011724

Comment: You can use standard string formatting `"Hello {name}!".format(name="Boris")` but `Jinja2` could be nicer if you would need `for`-loops to add many list of elements in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this depending on how dynamic this must be and how many elements you are going to need to insert.  If it is one single value `name` then @furas is correct and you can simply put

```
html = open("test.html", "r")
text = html.read().format(name="skeletor")
print(text)
```

And get:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>

   <body>
    Hello World, skeletor!
   </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you can use Jinja2 templates.

```
import jinja2
html = open("test.html", "r")
text = html.read()
t = jinja2.Template(text)
print(t.render(name="Skeletor"))
```

Helpful links: [Jinja website](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/)

[Real Python Primer on Jinja](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/)

[Python Programming Jinja](https://pythonprogramming.net/jinja-templates-django-python-tutorial/)