# Python script to generate letter does not read .csv well

Tags: python, csv, txt

Maybe you can help me troubleshoot. I am running this code to read a `.csv` file and us a sample `.txt` letter to generate a `.txt` file for each row of the `.csv` file. I name each file after the `Institution` column of the `.csv` file.

```
import csv
import os

# Define the path to the directory where you want to save the files
directory_path = r'C:\Users'

# Set the current working directory to the specified path
os.chdir(directory_path)

# Define the CSV and sample text file names
csv_file = "sample.csv"
sample_text_file = "sample_template.txt"

# Read the CSV file
with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    data = list(csv_reader)

# Read the sample text template
with open(sample_text_file, 'r') as template_file:
    template_text = template_file.read()

# Define the placeholders without delimiters
placeholders = ["Position", "Platform", "Institution", "Optional Paragraph"]

# Process each row from the CSV
for row in data:
    # Create a copy of the template text for this row
    modified_text = template_text

    # Replace placeholders with values from the CSV
    for placeholder in placeholders:
        value = row.get(placeholder, '')
        modified_text = modified_text.replace(f'"{placeholder}"', value)

    # Get the name for the output file from "Institution" column
    output_file_name = f"{row['Institution']}.txt"

    # Write the modified text to the output file
    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(modified_text)

    print(f"File '{output_file_name}' has been created.")

print("All files have been generated in the specified directory.")
```

The `.txt` file is written to be exported to latex and looks like this:

```
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIRST PAGE HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace{-1em} % Pull the rule closer to the logo

\rule{\linewidth}{1pt} % Horizontal rule

\bigskip\bigskip % Vertical whitespace

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l @{}}
    \today \bigskip\\ % Date
    NAME \\
        INSTITUTION \\
    A1 \\ % Address
    A2 \\
\end{tabular}

Dear Members of the Recruiting Committee,
\bigskip % Vertical whitespace

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am writing to apply for the "Position" position that you have advertised on "Platform". 

I believe the skills and competencies I hold would be of great value to the "Institution".


"Optional Paragraph"

Thank you for your time and consideration. 

\bigskip % Vertical whitespace

Sincerely yours,

\vspace{50pt} % Vertical whitespace

\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{signature.png}

NAME

\end{document}
```

And the sample `.csv` looks like this:

```
Position,Platform,Institution,Optional Paragraph
Waiter,Facebook,Company A ,
Coder,Twitter,Company B,I am cool.
```

**My problem is that this gives me the following result for Company A:**

```
I am writing to apply for the  position that you have advertised on Facebook. 

I believe the skills and competencies I hold would be of great value to the Company A .
```

As you can see, the `Position` column is not recognized by my code. I was wondering if you had thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: Show us the actual text content of the csv file, not an image.

Comment: The actual text allows folks to see if you have an error like having an extra space in your input that would make your column heading actually "Position ".  I also suggest checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385686/is-there-a-native-templating-system-for-plain-text-files-in-python.  That answer provides a number of options for solving your problem without having to write your own templating system.

Comment: Sorry, just updated with the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a BOM (byte order marker) in your CSV file, like:

```py
with open("input.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    f.write(
        """Position,Platform,Institution,Optional Paragraph
Waiter,Facebook,Company A ,
Coder,Twitter,Company B,I am cool."""
    )

with open("input.csv", "rb") as f:
    print(f.read(12))
```

that looks like:

```py
b'\xef\xbb\xbfPosition,'
```

When the DictReader gets that underlying file and reads the first line as the fieldnames, the BOM is read as part of the first column name:

```py
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    print(reader.fieldnames)
```

```py
['\ufeffPosition', 'Platform', 'Institution', 'Optional Paragraph']
```

So `'Position' != '\ufeffPosition'`, and that's why your get(fieldname, '') returns an empty string.

Try that code above, printing the fieldnames, and if you see `\ufeff`, open the file with `encoding='utf-8-sig'`:

```py
with open("input.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    print(reader.fieldnames)
```

```py
['Position', 'Platform', 'Institution', 'Optional Paragraph']
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!!